# Images on Safari appearing as question marks

Tags: html, image, safari

Sometimes, the images on certain web pages, appear as blue boxes with question marks.

Does it have to do with wrong markup or some file format that Safari can't recognize?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with certain image or are you asking for a comprehensive list of all possible reasons?

Comment: I have noticed it several times, only on Safari and I was wondering if there might be some well-known issue, like Safari being too picky on the image encoding or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by an image with the wrong src attribute. For instance, an image like this:
`<img src="link/to/non/existent/image.jpg" />`
Would show the blue box with a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

Well, recently I have found out that it's an issue connected to wrong DNS.
Please open your Network Settings in Preference pane, then go to your active connection, press Advanced, go to DNS tab and try replacing DNS to for instance 8.8.8.8
It solved the issue for me